# regex help getting a value from url

Tags: php

i have this

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFyHi2aIJIV7kAlui1Sd_MQGosiBA&amp;url=http://ksa.daralhayat.com/ksaarticle/192445
```

i want to get the value of **url=** only

Answer (score 7):

```
$url = html_entity_decode($url);
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'],$params);
echo $params['url'];
```

Comment: Hehe, I'm glad you also went the 'do not use the regex route' then :)

Comment: +1 No reason creating "parsers" where others have made them before.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness the you can `preg_match` with that:

```
/^.*url\=(.*)$/
```

But you should prefer the `parse_url()` method that is really faster than a RegEx.

Comment: What if there are more occurrences of `url=` than one?

Comment: I'm assuming that can't happens in a regular-formed url.
However, it matches the last one.